# excluding some folders in tar command not work

Tags: linux, tar

I run this command to compress the content of current folder while excluding some directories:

```
mahmood@mpc:set3-HHLL$ l
file1.txt    a/     c/
file2.inp    b/     ...
mahmood@mpc:set3-HHLL$ tar cvjf ../set3.tar.bz2 * --exclude=a/ --exclude=b/ --exclude=c/
```

However in the output I see:

```
file1.txt
file2.inp
a/1.out
a/2.out
2/1.out
...
```

Why it ignores the command line options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command would be:

```
tar cvjf ../set3.tar.bz2 * --exclude='a' --exclude='b' --exclude='c'
```